# Vue.js - Table gets updated but selected checkbox data does not

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've ran into a bug that I can't seem to solve. I have a table with selectable rows. When a checkbox is checked, the amount column is summed up.

But, when the data in the table changes using a datepicker, the merchant total on the right and the amount in the selected checkboxes object do not update and reflect what is in the table.

Below are two images illustrating what's happening.

**Here is a codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NmKBjm

**Solved the issue but I believe there's a more optimal method using v-model but I just can't get it to work. I'm basically fetching the data and then re-assigning the selected object with the data.**

```html
this.volume = response.data;

this.total = this.volume.reduce(function(p, n) {
    return p + parseFloat(n.amount);
}, 0);

let merchants = this.selected.map(m => m.merchantName);
let filterMerchants = this.volume.filter(e => e ? merchants.includes(e.merchantName) : null);

this.selected = filterMerchants;
this.onCheckboxChange();
```

[image]

[image]

And here is my code.

```html
<v-data-table v-model="selected" id="transactions-volume-table" :headers="tableHeaders" :items="volume" item-key="merchantName" :loading="loading" :search="searchTable" hide-actions class="elevation-1">
<v-progress-linear slot="progress" color="blue" indeterminate></v-progress-linear>
<template v-slot:items="props">
    <td><v-checkbox v-model="props.selected" @change="onCheckboxChange" primary hide-details></v-checkbox></td>
    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.divisionName }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.merchantName }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-left">£{{ props.item.amount.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") }}</td>
</template>
</v-data-table>

data() {
  return {
      search: {
          fromDate: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
          toDate: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)
      },
      fromDateModal: false,
      toDateModal: false,
      searchTable: '',
      loading: true,
      volume: [],
      total: null,
      merchantTotal: 0,
      tableHeaders: [{ text: 'Select', sortable: false },
                     { text: 'Division', value: 'divisionName', sortable: true },
                     { text: 'Merchant', value: 'merchantName', sortable: true },
                     { text: 'Amount (£)', value: 'amount', sortable: true }],
      selected: []
  }
}

onCheckboxChange() {
    console.log(this.selected);
    this.merchantTotal = this.selected.reduce(function(p, n) {
        return p + parseFloat(n.amount);
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You update the merchant total only if a checkbox changes. You should update the merchant total in case your dates change as well. Because the date change it does not trigger a checkbox to change event.

**EDIT**
<s>No, because the checkbox change event only gets triggered when it changes(click on it or manually fired). Your merchantTotal isn't a computed property so it isn't acting on anything. You can try and make it computed, actually it's a computed action you are trying to mimic.</s>

**EDIT**
<s>Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ofcuLqdr/3/) I created. Like your example everything is working around the `selected` rows. In cases the selected variable changes (after applied filters or toggle a checkbox on or of) it will re-computed the total. In my example I use products in stead of merchants, but in function it's doing the same.</s>

**EDIT**
Are you able to add a unique identifier foreach merchant in the dataset? Or you can create a ID based on 2 rows (division and merchantname). Its the only way around this is calculate the data via the volume (based on the selected merchant id or unique identifier, like I illustrated). Another way to do it is when data changes you unselect the merchants, but this is not really user friendly.

I thought it was a Vue implementation problem, but I think the problem lies within the working of the datatable from Vuetify (in your situation).

Comment: Even if I call that function when the data changes, nothing happens. Also, because the table has v-model="selected", shouldn't that automatically update the selected object when the table updates?

Comment: Check my edit, so merchantTotal should be a computed property.

Comment: But the merchantTotal is derived from the amount of each merchant selected. If the selected object is not updating, the merchantTotal won't update either. As you can see in both pics, that's the output of {{ selected }}.

As selected is set as a v-model for the table and the checkboxes have v-model="props.selected", I don't see why this isn't working.

Comment: Still not the problem I'm facing mate. Check our my codepen in my original post. Everything works fine until the data in the table is updated. When the data gets update, this isn't reflected onto the select object.

Comment: I see the problem. Vuetify is making a duplicated from your data, when selecting a row. I dunno how the data-tables internally work and if there is a working around for when the source data changes...

Comment: Check my original post mate.

Comment: Not the most optimal way of achieving it, but I think it's a vuetify problem.. if it works it ain't stupid 

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad. Reformulation.

Vue has a limitation in reactivity to detect changes in objects. That is the problem, you can not know when your volume array change because datepicker changes. You should use this.$set to detect the changes in objects (an array is an object).

Link: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

This is a sample code:

```
<div id="app">
    {{ message[0] }}
    <button v-on:click="change">Change</button>
</div>


<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: [45,35,50]
        },
        methods: {
            change: function () {
                //this.$set(this.message, 0, 35);                    
                message[0] = 35;
                console.log(this.message);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

uncomment the line commented and try, you will see the difference.

Comment: Yes I'm using Vuetify. Emptying the selected array unchecks all the checkboxes and sets the value to zero. This isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Look my codepen https://codepen.io/edu1464/pen/zXOQNX?editors=1010

I solve the problem using computed properties and watchers.